"Evaluating a Triple Integral Over a Unit Ball Using Spherical Coordinates and a Variable Shift"
Let $B$ be the unit ball centered at the origin with $a>1$ . I want to evaluate the following integral:
$$ \iiint_{B} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2 + (z-a)^2}} dxdydz$$
Using spherical coordinates with:   $x = \rho\sin(\phi) \cos(\theta)$ , $ y = \rho \sin(\phi) \sin(\theta)$ ,  $ z = \rho \cos(\phi) $ . The integral becomes:
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{\rho^2 \sin(\phi)}{\sqrt{ \rho^2 - 2a \cos(\phi) + a^2}} d\rho d\phi d\theta $$
However, this integral seems complicated to solve. To simplify, I considered the following change of variables: $x = \rho\sin(\phi) \cos(\theta)$ , $ y = \rho \sin(\phi) \sin(\theta)$ ,  $ z = \rho \cos(\phi) + a$.
The challenge now is to determine the new integration limits in this configuration. This new change should make the integral calculation easier. Any suggestions on how to establish the new limits or how to solve the problem in an easier way would be of great help.

Note you're missing a $\rho$ in the middle term under the square root.

The function $f(x,y,z) = 1/\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-a)^2}$ is harmonic. By the mean value formula, the requested integral is $4\pi/(3a)$.

I like the harmonicity proof, but here is an elementary calculation. Write the integral by iterating in a non-standard order:
$$I=2\pi\int_0^1\int_0^\pi \frac{\rho^2\sin\phi}{(\rho^2-2a\rho\cos\phi+a^2)^{1/2}}\,d\phi\,d\rho.$$
Now, fixing $\rho$, set $u=\rho^2-2a\rho\cos\phi+a^2$, with $du=2a\rho\sin\phi\,d\phi$.
Then
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\pi\frac{\rho^2\sin\phi}{(\rho^2-2a\rho\cos\phi+a^2)^{1/2}}\,d\phi &=  \int_{(a-\rho)^2}^{(a+\rho)^2} u^{-1/2}\frac{\rho}{2a}du \\
&=\frac\rho a u^{1/2}\Big]_{(a-\rho)^2}^{(a+\rho)^2} = \frac\rho a (2\rho) = \frac{2\rho^2}a.
\end{align*}
(Note that we use $a>1\ge\rho$ at the last step.)
So now we have $I = 2\pi\displaystyle{\int_0^1 \frac{2\rho^2}a d\rho = \frac{4\pi}{3a}}$, as desired.

Thank you so much

You’re welcome. You should consider accepting one of the answers at this point.

your region is the unit ball
$x^2+y^2 + z^2 \le 1$
The new coordinates are:
$x=\rho \cos \theta\sin\phi\\
y = \rho \sin \theta\sin\phi\\
z = \rho \cos\phi + \alpha$
Plug these into our equation of the region and simplify....
$(\rho\cos\theta\sin\phi)^2 + (\rho\sin\theta\sin\phi)^2 + (\rho\cos\phi + \alpha)^2 = 1$
$(\rho\cos\theta\sin\phi)^2 + (\rho\sin\theta\sin\phi)^2 + (\rho\cos\phi)^2 + 2\rho\cos\phi\alpha + \alpha^2 = 1$
$\rho^2 + 2\rho\alpha \cos\phi + \alpha^2 - 1 = 0$
$\theta$ is not bounded so $0$ to $2\pi$
$\rho = -\alpha \cos\phi \pm \sqrt {\alpha^2 \cos^2\phi - \alpha^2 + 1}$
$\rho = -\alpha \cos\phi \pm\sqrt {1-\alpha^2\sin^2\phi}$
$-\alpha\cos\phi - \sqrt {1-\alpha^2\sin^2\phi} \le \rho \le -\alpha\cos\phi + \sqrt {1-\alpha^2\sin^2\phi}$
$1-\alpha^2\sin^2\phi \ge 0$
If $\alpha < 1$ we have no further restriction on $\phi$
otherwise $\sin \phi \le |\frac {1}{\alpha}|$
$\pi-\arcsin |\frac {1}\alpha| \le \phi \le \pi + \arcsin |\frac 1{\alpha}|$
We need to add $\pi$ in order to make $\rho > 0$
I don't think it makes your integrand any easier to solve, but hopefully gives you some insight in coordinate transformations.

Thank you so much
